# Что означает аннотация @FormUrlEncoded в библиотеке Retrofit 2.0?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Есть код отправки Post запроса с полями phone и lang в теле запроса. Без FormUrlEncoded это дело не работает. Что означает эта аннотация и зачем она нужна? Я пытался засунуть тело запроса иначе, но не получилось.

```
public interface SmsApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("phone_add/{id}")
    Call<PhoneAddModel> phoneAdd(@Path("id") String id,
                           @Field("phone") String phone,
                           @Field("lang") String lang);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы [её описание](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/FormUrlEncoded.html) смотреть не пробовали? Эта аннотация определяет одноименный формат передачи полей в теле POST запроса. Грубо говоря записывает эти поля в тело запроса в таком же формате как они были бы записаны в URL строку при GET запросе.

Comment: Грубо говоря, это нечто подобное что и @Query для GET запроса?

Comment: Можно и так наверное сказать